# Получение коллеции произвольного типа

Tags: c#, коллекции, generics

После продолжительно перерыва вернулся на C#.

Можно ли сделать, как на Java?

Есть метод:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static <T> List<T> list() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }    
}
```

И я его вызываю в разных местах, где мне надо коллекция:

```
List<Integer> i = MyUtils.list();
```

или так:

```
List<MyType> t = MyUtils.list();
```

Как сделать такое же на шарпе? В том плане, чтобы в функцию list явно не передавать тип.

Comment: в шарпе удобнее делать так


    var i = new List<Integer>();
    var t = new List<MyType>();

Comment: А это, наверное, и есть ответ на вопрос. Нельзя сделать так, чтобы в функцию list явно не передавать тип, так как:

    var i = MyUtils.list();

будет неопределенным.

Comment: Наверно вы правы. Я как-то сразу в лоб пошёл. В java это ещё объяснимо было. Потому что список обычно объявляю через интерфейс List, а чтобы создать, нужно уже вызвать ArrayList, т.е. подлиннее получается.

Comment: Хотя в целом вопрос может быть ещё и открыт. Если также переносить в MyUtils функции list(), где в качестве входных параметров передаётся другая коллекция, или список коллекций (...) или просто список аргументов с тем же типом, что и сама итоговая коллекция.

Comment: Увидел Ваше второе сообщение после того, как уже написал, здесь я несогласен - в шарпе нельзя, а в яве пожалуйста :)

Comment: Я ничего не хочу сказать плохого про вопрос, вопрос замечательный, я сам много нового узнал из него. Но у меня растет и крепнет убеждение, что в реальной программе надобность в таких фокусах объясняется или плохим кодом, или плохим пониманием задачи, или плохим знанием возможностей C# (т.е. попыткой программировать на одном языке в стиле другого языка, с привнесением всех недостатков языка-донора, которых в другом языке и не было отродясь). Скажите, в какой ситуации это надо, и наверняка найдется более "сишарпный" способ решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static List<T> list<T>() {
        return new List<T>();
    }    
}
```

Используется так:

```
List<int> i = MyUtils.list<int>();
List<string> s = MyUtils.list<string>();
```

Comment: На данный момент так и сделал. Но как и говорил, хочется без явного указания типа.

Comment: Ага, недосмотрел. Хороший вопрос :)